# Forcing to use 3g over Wi-Fi Android

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

I have an issue with an application I'm developing for Android 2.3.3.

It's connected to a Wi-Fi access point, and at the same time it is supposed to download some data, but this has to be done using 3G.

I tried searching for this, and found some relevant stuff but could not make it work. I checked out the `setNetworkPreference` method of the ConnectivityManager, and, even when set to use 3G, it does not download the data and ends up downloading it via Wi-Fi.

Any other ideas how I can do this without disconnecting from the Wi-Fi access point?

Comment: This seems like it would be an awfully dangerous feature for Android to allow. What about users who are on metered 3G plans? How would they feel if an app forced them to use a 3G connection and then bugged out or something and blew away their whole data quota without them even knowing it (thinking they were on WiFi)?

Comment: Why do you have to use 3G? Only case I can think of is the user is connected to a Wifi connection that doesn't really grant them access to the internet (requires sign in like at hotels or sometimes coffee shops). But I have to agree with eldarerathis, there's no way you should take it upon yourself to get around this without asking the user.

Comment: Actually its supposed to be for research purposes, I don't intend to use it for anything malicious. In fact every user would be told before hand about the way this app functions.

Comment: If you have found something out as of today, that would be of a great help for me :> I can't convince myself that I'll have to force disabling WiFi considering my app is supposed not to be of any inconvenience !

Comment: @PeterGriffin I found a method. Try searching for a method called requestRouteToHost. It allows you to specify the network type and the host you want to find a route to. You will find some code examples if you google it. The downside is this function has an expiry time so it works just for 1 minute. So I was forced to actually turn off WiFi while using 3G and then turn the WiFi on later when done with the 3G job.

Answer (score 1):

I literally just came across this on another forum.  It looks like the solution to your question.

ICS tends to automatically add proxys to APN info which sometimes makes apps not work on 3G.

Thread says the following...

"This helped a couple of people on a Dutch forum, don't know if it's provider or country-related and if there even are users here that have these issues, but still wanted to let you know:

I have just fixed why some apps work only with WiFi but not on 3G. ICS apparently automatically added Proxy-settings to your APN, in my case Vodafone (NL). This is not necesarry to even make use of mobile internet, and it also prevents some apps from accessing the internet. I removed the Proxy-settings et voila, it works perfectly again!

Fix: Settings -> Press 'Mobile Network' (not Off-On!) -> Names accespoints -> Click your provider -> Remove 'Proxy' and 'Port'"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I have found a solution to my problem. There's a method called requestRouteToHost which allows you to specify the network type and the host you want to find a route to. Now the problem I am facing is this method works for HTC devices and for a Samsung Galaxy S3 it returns false always and does not work. And yes I checked out, there is no proxy or port number added for my network provider's access point.